# XAML code to put button in bottom right corner

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get my floating action button in the bottom left corner of my application.

Currently it looks like this:

[image: How I don't want it]

And I want it to look like this:

[image: What I want]

My XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxx;assembly=xxx"
         x:Class="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx"> 

 <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  Margin="0,15,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
                <!--<local:CustomImage Source="logo.png" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Center" />-->

                <local:CustomImageButton  WidthRequest="150" Image="Foto.png" ClassId="Eigendommen" x:Name="buttonFoto" HeightRequest="150"/>

            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="MainStack" >
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="#F15A35" HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="400" Margin="0,-2,0,5" />
                <Label Text="Toegevoegd:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  IsVisible="False" Margin="10,0,10,0" x:Name="hideImage1">
                        <local:CustomImage HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="Verwijderen" FontSize="Small" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                            <local:CustomImageButton Image="close_zwart.png" BackgroundColor="White" Clicked="Hide_Image_Click" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0,10,0" x:Name="hideImage2" IsVisible="False">
                        <local:CustomImage HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="Verwijderen" FontSize="Small" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                            <local:CustomImageButton Image="close_zwart.png" Clicked="Hide_Image_Click" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0,10,0" x:Name="hideImage3" IsVisible="False">
                        <local:CustomImage HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="Verwijderen" FontSize="Small" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                            <local:CustomImageButton Image="close_zwart.png" Clicked="Hide_Image_Click" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout 
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,0.25,0.25">

        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <local:FloatingActionButton Image="checktaak.png" x:Name="insertTaak"  HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" />
        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>

</AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

You can find the my floating action button at the bottom of all the code ( the last stacklayout). if you need more code let me know in the comments.
**Edit** I want the button always there even if it overlaps a other stacklayout

Comment: My Xamarin enviroment is not installed here, but I can help: Put the Button inside AbsoluteLayout, outside the StackLayout.

Comment: I did that and my button his renderer did something weird. Normally the button needs to be round but than it only had round corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

Just had to tweak the layoutbounds a little, I didn't knew I could go over 1.
This is my new layoutbound for the stacklayout that includes the fab:

```
 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.94,1.18,0.5,0.25"
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `FloatingActionButton` inherits from `Button` and the `AbsoluteLayout` is the child of a `ContentPage` and the expected margin for the floating button as (15,15) from right and bottom borders,

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <!-- SOME OTHER ELEMENTS -->

    <local:FloatingActionButton Image="checktaak.png"
                                CornerRadius="30"
                                WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="60"
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,75,75"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

### To NOTE,

- Use `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"` to make
  only the positioning proportional

  Then for `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` set `X` and `Y`, 1 and 1 to
  push it to the bottom right corner. The `Width` and `Height` is set
  to 75 and 75 to position the element 75 points left from the layout's
  right border and 75 points top from the layout's bottom border.

  > The 75 is calculated as,
  >
  > `60(element width/height request) + 15(right/bottom margin) = 75`
- Since the `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` is 60, half of it 30
  will be the `CornerRadius` of the element.